# Why Junit parser failed when running Jmeter scripts with Bamboo?

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

*

> **Please note** that this is working fine in my local machine jmeter, only
>   issue happening when running with bamboo

*

**Bamboo Script configuration**

```
sh /apps/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/jmeter \

-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml \

-n -t Repo/test.jmx \
-l ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/test.jtl
echo -e "/////////////////////////////TEST LOG DETAILS////////////////////////"
cat test.jtl

java -jar /apps/install/m2u.jar --input 
${bamboo.build.working.directory}/test.jtl --output ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/test.jmx
```

---

**Bamboo log**

[image]

Comment: Is there any special reason for using deprecated Stepping Thread Group plugin instead of https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup ?

Comment: My plan is to run is to run this for 500 simultaneous connections which needs to build by say 100 every 5 minutes. after that reduce at the samerate.[but this time i need to run for atleast 1 user to fix this issue in bamboo]